# Acessing result of a Query

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm beginner in Java but I has the following code

```
limit = con.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM San_CadastraDigital WHERE Cliente_Id = ?");


public String Verify(String client) {
    try {
        limit.setString(1, client);
        ResultSet rs = limit.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            int limitDigital = rs.getInt(0);            
            if (limitDigital < 3) {
                return "1";
            } else {
                return "0";
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        ui.writeLog(e.getMessage());
        return "0";
    }

    return "0";
}
```

But I got an error that said that column in index 0 is out of the range.

My query works fine in my database.

How can I get the result of my query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API docs for ResultSet#getInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29):

> columnIndex - **the first column is 1**, the second is 2, ...

Comment: I got this error when I put column 1, The requested operation is not supported on sets of forward-only results.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos Did you try the code suggested by nolegs? If so revert back to your original code and only change `getInt(0)` to `getInt(1)`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
        if(!rc.first())
        {
          //no rows
          return "0";
        }

        do {
            int limitDigital = rs.getInt(0);            
            if (limitDigital < 3) {
                return "1";
            } else {
                return "0";
            }
        } while (rs.next())
```

I think you are moving the cursor with rs.next() and skipping the first result.

Comment: with this code I got the error: The result set has no current row.

Comment: has difference in my code if I put instead int limitDigital = rs.getInt(0); put String limitDigital = rs.getString(0);

Comment: Using methods like `first()` on a `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` ResultSet can result in errors in some drivers. It is best to simply use `next()` if you are going to process rows one by one in the same order as they are returned.